# kextload: command not found

Tags: macos, kernel-extensions

Strange, I have access to other kext utilities such as `kextcache`, `kextfind`, `kextlibs`, `kextstat`, `kextunload`, `kextutil` but not `kextload`. Is there any cause for that ?

---

**Edit - 1** : `kextload` files;

```
➜ locate 'kextload'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/share/man/man8/kextload.8
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/share/man/man8/logkextloadsd.8
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/share/man/man8/kextload.8
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/share/man/man8/logkextloadsd.8
/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.logkextloadsd.plist
/usr/libexec/logkextloadsd
/usr/share/man/man8/kextload.8
/usr/share/man/man8/logkextloadsd.8
```

**Edit - 2** : Context of problem

Was trying to [reload kext files of VirtualBox](https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask/issues/39369#issuecomment-339118861) because they were not automatically loaded. To reload them, I had to unload with `kextunload`and load with `kextload`. I was able to run `'kextunload` but not `kextload` because it was unavailable. Access to other kext utilities are available, But not `kextload`. Why is it unavailable ?

I was able to load kext with `kextutil -l`, VirtualBox still not working.

Comment: Sorry, I should've been specific. Details are added to question.

Comment: You may have inadvertantly deleted it.  You should be able to get it back by copying it from a source that has it (try Recovery) and copy it back.  It's located in `/usr/sbin`

Comment: Santa Claus told me you don't have access to `kextunload` too.

Comment: Please ask your question.

Comment: `which kextload`should give you the location of kextload that is usually in the `sbin`folder. Otherwise you should check your bash profile for the correct paths.

Answer (score 1):

Check your `${PATH}`. For a reason to investigate, `/sbin` isn't included in it. And `kextload` is:

```
/sbin/kextload
```

When, for example, `kextstat` is:

```
/usr/sbin/kextstat
```

The difference of location is fully correct (one is an admin command, the other not).

Comment: `/sbin` is in my `PATH` and `kextload` is not there. May be it was accidentally deleted, I'll try to recover it.

Comment: Check for this possible error with `ls -ldT /sbin`.